# Remove slow motion from video in MacOS

Tags: macos, photos, mov

I have some videos I made on my iPhone and copied to my computer.  I deleted them from my iPhone.

Now when I play them though using Photos v4.0 on macOS 10.14.2 I see parts are in slow motion.  They are .MOV files.

How can I fix them so they do not play in slow motion?

Comment: Can you open them in QuickTime or iMovie on the computer and edit in the information showing how the video files are encoded? We're kind of guessing if you have a Mac or Windows or linux or some other sort of computer. Hopefully, the copied movies still have all the data so you can use them like the slow motion captures where Apple allows you to set a start / end time of the slow portion.

Comment: Did you record those parts that are in slo-mo as slo-mo? Or is this an unwanted side effect?

Comment: I think I must have recorded parts in slow motion.   I didn't do it intentionally.

Comment: @bmike I have a macbook I can work with them now.  I suppose I can airdrop them back to the iphone if that will let me edit them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag both slo-mo handles over each other so that they are both either at the beginning or at the end of the video.
E.g. drag the right slo-mo handle all to the left or vice versa.

[image]

Comment: oh geez.  I saw those sliders and tried to move them before I asked, but wasn't able to.  I must have clicked poorly as this time I can move them.

Comment: How to "save this" so that the video is normal speed?

Comment: Except this is not saved if you try to airdrop or otherwise send the file anywhere….